# Incron Won't Execute a Script But Cron Will, Permission Denied

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a simple script to run rclone.  It executes properly from the root command line.  It also executes properly when called by a regular cron job.  Permissions of the script are set as root/root 0755, i.e. it's executable.  (So is rclone.)

The following line is the incron job as set by `incrontab -e` and as confirmed with `icrontab -l`

`/var/vhosts/localdir IN_ALL_EVENTS /bin/rclonescript.sh`

The following is my script that runs from the command line or from a regular cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/rclone copy /var/vhosts/localdir mygoogledrive:uploadfolder
```

Here is the output from `tail -f /var/log/cron`:

```
Mar 16 18:45:55 localhost incrond[8215]: (root) CMD (/bin/rclonescript.sh)
```

The output looks okay, but the script is not run.

This is how the cron log looks when the script is successfully called from a cron job `* * * * * /bin/rclonescript.sh`:

```
Mar 16 18:59:01 localhost CROND[9070]: (root) CMD (/bin/rclonescript.sh)
```

The log is practically the same, but the cron job works.  Incron does not.

I've tried setting the path in my script, first by checking:

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

...then adding the path to the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
Path=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin   
/usr/sbin/rclone copy /var/vhosts/localdir mygoogledrive:uploadfolder
```

When I attempt this as the inclone job:

```
/var/vhosts/anne_scan IN_ALL_EVENTS,IN_NO_LOOP /bin bash rclonescript.sh
```

or

```
/var/vhosts/anne_scan IN_ALL_EVENTS,IN_NO_LOOP /bin rclonescript.sh
```

It results in permission denied:

```
Mar 17 09:00:27 localhost incrond[24917]: cannot exec process: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `sudo` before the command, like this:

```
/var/vhosts/watcheddir IN_ALL_EVENTS,IN_NO_LOOP sudo /bin/sh /bin/yourscript.sh
```

Select the user like this:

```
/var/vhosts/watcheddir IN_ALL_EVENTS,IN_NO_LOOP sudo -u username /bin/sh /bin/yourscript.sh
```